# How to resolve AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' in python

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup

```
for comment_entry in comment_feed.entry:
content = comment_entry.ToString()
parse = BeautifulSoup(content)
for con in parse.find('ns0:content'):
    print con.string
    s = con.string
    file.write(s.encode('utf8'))
```

Error which I'm getting:

```
File "channel_search.py", line 108, in youtube_search
file.write(s.encode('utf8'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: what does print con.string gives you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `s` might be *Nonetype*

Try

```
s = con.string
if s:file.write(s.encode('utf8'))
# or if s is not None        
#if you want to check only for None
```